# Making a GridView that wraps its height and width according to the data inside

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I am trying to create a gridview that adjusts its width and height according to the ImageView width and height in each cell. My script does'nt seems to work that way. I can't figure it what i'm doing wrong. I have attached sample images of what i'm trying to do. These screenshots were taken from an application on google play store. [image]

Here is my .xml file that has the GridView that will populate Data

```html
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_client_newsfeed_xml"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="NO ITEM ADDED YET USE DETAIL BUTTON TO GO FURTHER"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/list_view_client_newsfeed_xml"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            >

        </GridView>
        
       </RelativeLayout>
```

here is my getView method of the adapter class that downloads image and populate it in gridView. I'm using Picasso to download images from server. `

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolderClientNewsFeed holder;
        if (null == convertView) {

            holder = new ViewHolderClientNewsFeed();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_view_images_client_newsfeed, parent, false);
            holder.newsfeedImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_clientNewaFeed);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolderClientNewsFeed) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Picasso.with(context)
            .load(imageUrls.get(position))
            .fit()
            .into(holder.newsfeedImage);

        return convertView;
    }
```

`
Here is my List Row layout for newsfeed.

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_clientNewaFeed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone please point out what im doing wrong. I want to achieve something in the inserted image.

Comment: You are giving your image views fixed width and height, that's not going to change whatever you do with your grid, which part should be dynamic to "wrap"?

Comment: Yeah i saw your point, i have edited it. I also tried using wrap_content in my ImageView that im using inside my gridview on runtime. But the gridView cells don't seem to adjust there width and height according to the image inside. They are the same no matter what sized image is downloaded at runtime. I want my girdview cell to adjust themselves as the sized image in them

Comment: You want the cells to adjust, or the whole grid? You grid has match_parent, so it won't get any smaller or bigger. Show screen shot of the wrong layout please

Comment: I want the cells to adjust accordingly. I want to make a menu like that image above.

Comment: You want cells to fill the width, but they are not? there are white spaces? you're making it difficult using imagination :D

Comment: Yes exactly, i want the image to fill the space, There are white spaces in each cell in my case. Thank you so much you used the right term. Thats exactly whats happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your images are not filling the width of your view, it's because they are basically smaller than your phone/tablet width.

You basically need to change the `scaleType` of your `ImageView`.

use `FIT_XY` will do the trick, but might stretch your images, you can also try `CENTER_CROP`, `CENTER_INSIDE` or `FIT_CENTER`.

You might need to set `android:adjustViewBounds` to true on your `ImageView`s

Comment: Thank you for your  advice, it really helped in filling up the empty spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create view as staggered grid view,
you can search on google about staggered grid layout 
[here](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid) is what i found.

Comment: This GridView seems good, i will surely take a look at this, Thank you so much for sharing